# How to redirect the traffic from http://mydomain.com.br-my-account to port 443 (.htaccess)?

Tags: .htaccess

Friends, I need to redirect the traffic from http://mydomain.com.br/my-account to the port 443. I have found out that I can do that with the help of .htaccess but kind of don't know how. I've found some exemples but I still don't undestand how this works so that I can't adjust the exemple to my needs.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^http://mydomain\.com.br [NC]
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://mydomain.com.br/$1 [R,L]
```

Comment: Can you give examples of before and after URIs? Currently you seem to be redirecting to a different domain entirely?

Comment: I still haven't tried to redirect, still trying to find out how.

Comment: To be clear are you simply trying to enable `https`?

Comment: Also, is `my-account` a _page_ or a _place holder_?